# $routeParams not being injected into factory call to $resource

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a call to a service using `$resource`. I'm passing a parameter from one controller to the other. I've checked and the parameter is indeed getting passed. The problem is it is not being picked up within my factory:

Here is the call to the factory with the `$routeParam`:

```
  $scope.others = getOthersFactory.getOtherOrgs($routeParams.acnId);
```

Here is the factory:

```
app.factory('getOthersFactory', ['$resource', 'domain', function ($resource, domain) {
    return $resource('/api/acn/:id/OtherNetworkOrgs', {id:'@acnId'}, {
        getOtherOrgs: {method:'GET'}
    });
}])
```

The result I get is this:

http://localhost:16000/api/acn/OtherNetworkOrgs

when it should be:

http://localhost:16000/api/acn/#/OtherNetworkOrgs

where # is the ID of the acn.

Comment: Hi Charlietfl, the hash represents a number ID. Which is what I meant when I said "where # is the ID of the acn. Appreciate the input, but that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you being calling the function like this:

```
$scope.others = getOthersFactory.getOtherOrgs({ id: $routeParams.acnId });
```

Comment: Thanks ThiagoPXP! I can't believe I missed that.